# Implicitly unwrapped optional Closure in a method argument

Tags: swift, closures, option-type

In [SwiftHTTP](https://github.com/daltoniam/SwiftHTTP/blob/master/HTTPTask.swift), it has this following code for its GET method:

```
public func GET(url: String, 
                parameters: Dictionary<String,AnyObject>?, 
                completionHandler:((HTTPResponse) -> Void)!) { ... }
```

By making this implicitly unwrapped optional, does it mean the completionHandler must be provided? If so why bother making it an optional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implicitly unwrapped optional means you technically *can* pass nil, but whether or not it crashes depends on the rest of the code. In this case, [it appears](https://github.com/daltoniam/SwiftHTTP/blob/28a96a08497f64771f946cfd2912e3215c64ab39/HTTPTask.swift#L197) that the case where completionHandler is nil is handled properly (so you don't have to provide one). I would simply say this is a sub-optimal API :)

Comment: Thanks @jtbandes. How would you improve this, by using Optional instead?

Comment: The API should simply be clear about whether the completionHandler is required or not. It could be `HTTPResponse -> Void` or it could be `(HTTPResponse -> Void)?`.  (Also, an API for making requests to URLs should accept `NSURL`, not `String`!)

Comment: First point is well taken.  The latter point is interesting. The benefit of using String is possibly for increased flexibility (e.g. URL can be relative).